# Problem on contraction map

Tags: real-analysis

Let $g:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a function such that $\forall x,y\in \Bbb R,  |g(x) -g(y)|< \alpha |x-y|, 0<\alpha<1$.

Then is it true that $\lim_{s\to \infty}\frac{g(sx)}{s}$ exists for all $x$.

Not getting counter example.